# Google Cloud Pub/Sub error "Closed subscriber cannot be used as context manager" when trying to unsubscribe

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm getting the following error when trying to unsubscribe from a topic in Google Pub/Sub.

```py
self = <google.cloud.pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient object at 0x000002069A31D820>

    def __enter__(self) -> "Client":
        if self._closed:
>           raise RuntimeError("Closed subscriber cannot be used as context manager.")
E           RuntimeError: Closed subscriber cannot be used as context manager.

venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\subscriber\client.py:285: RuntimeError
```

Here is the relevant code, which is based on google's own [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-delete-subscription).

```py
    def unsubscribe(self, subscription_id):
        subscriber = self.subscriber

        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(self.project_id, subscription_id)

        with subscriber:
            subscriber.delete_subscription(request={"subscription": subscription_path})

        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, Google's own [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-delete-subscription) states that the code I was using would automatically close the subscription because of the `with` block. For some reason I kept overlooking that comment in the code.

This resolved my issue:

```py
    def unsubscribe(self, subscription_id):
        subscriber = self.subscriber

        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(self.project_id, subscription_id)

        subscriber.delete_subscription(request={"subscription": subscription_path})

        return True
```